# MySQL Optimize INFORMATION_SCHEMA Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 20,000 columns in my database, and a very frequently made query to list all of the columns of a specific table name pattern:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'pattern_%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my-db-name'
```

This is usually done quickly but sometimes takes some time (up to 10 seconds, I've seen once).

To optimize it, I thought to make an Index on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, however, as I understand, it is a view and I can't create an index for?

```sql
ALTER TABLE `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` ADD INDEX `table_name__table_schema` ( `TABLE_NAME` , `TABLE_SCHEMA` )
```

> 1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'information_schema'

There are 40 "patterns" overall that I use frequently.

Is there a way to optimize such that this query will be as fast as possible?

Query explain:
[image]

Comment: If you have so many tables with similar names, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Dynamic information should be in table data, not in the names of tables and columns.

Comment: Unless your table schema changes too often, which might be a hint for design problems, I'd suggest to add a caching layer within your application holding column metadata. You can invalidate and refresh as you see fit. In the mean time, you can query your metadata using this caching layer.

Comment: Thanks @Cascader, that is something I do do, the cache is valid for 1 hour, as it can definitely change, however, that first request to get the value to the cache is what I'm concerned about.

Comment: @Barmar my use case requires this to be done this way, I have many tables, each with millions of rows, and up to 500 columns.

Comment: Assuming MySQL 5.7 (please specify) you can go through the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-optimization.html) and pay extra attention on item 2 (_Write queries that minimize the number of table files that must be opened_). In your question, you `select *` which disables some optimizations.

Comment: BTW, you can't create an index on INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables because they are not actually tables, they are views. You can't optimize the table/schema so you need to focus on the query and/or your app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a materialised view as materialized view gets stored hence you would be able to create index on it. Below is the reference for materialized view syntax in mysql.

[Materialized view in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733970/materialized-view-in-mysql)

Although I wonder why you say sometimes runs late sometimes fast dont you think the more the data the more the time. View never gets stored correct but view still fetches few or all columns from the table. Did u try having an index on all the tables unique columns as view accesses the columns of table itself